# HTML5 min max on Safari

Tags: html, safari, mobile-safari

I have searched for it and according to W3School for instance `min` and `max`should work on Safari. However, the below code does work in Chrome for instance but not on Safari. Is it just for `datetime-local`or is this something else?
Code I'm using:
`<input type="datetime-local" name="dtime" min="2015-10-18T00:01:00">`

I'm testing this using Safari on iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No issue with the min and max attributes, but Safari doesn't support the `type="datetime-local"`

http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: Ok, but it loads the calendar in the device?

Comment: Yup, like the link says, iOS Safari has limited support. Safari on desktop has no support